# Angular6 - Project - You must install or update .NET to run this application

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, .net-core, backend

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2OI1.png)

> ERROR MESSAGE -
>
> C:\Users\HP\vega>dotnet run
>
> You must install or update .NET to run
> this application.
>
> App: C:\Users\HP\vega\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\vega.exe Architecture:
> x64 Framework: 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '3.0.3' (x64) .NET
> location: C:\Program Files\dotnet
>
> The following frameworks were found:
> 8.0.0 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>
> Learn more: https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed
>
> To install the missing framework, download:
> https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=3.0.3&arch=x64&rid=win-x64&os=win10

I am trying to run the Angular6 project by the command mentioned below.

dotnet new run

I have already installed the mentioned version under Microsoft.AspNetCore.App folder..But still it's showing the same issue.

Comment: So you've installed .NET Core 3.0?

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yes, I have installed .NET Core 3.0.3 as mentioned in the error.

Answer (score 1):

So it seems you've got both .NET 8 and the .NET Core 3 installed. When you have multiple .NET SDKs installed locally, you need to create a **global.json** file in the same directory as your **.sln** file to select a specific version: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json#examples

For .NET Core 3.0.x, you probably want something like:

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "3.0.0",
    "rollForward": "latestPatch"
  }
}
```

You can use the **dotnet** CLI tool to create a new **global.json** file:

`dotnet new globaljson --sdk-version 3.0.0`